# Struts 2: How to correctly move forward to other action?

Tags: struts2, friendly-url

I'm developing a Struts 2 project where I need to implement 2 friendly URLs. Since my 2 URLs need to be something like **URL/name/id** and **URL/id/title**, the only way I found to manager this was to use an 1st step action to process the request which then forwards to the correct Action1 or Action2, like this:

```
<action name="/*/*" class="web.ProcessRequestAction">
       <param name="firstParam">{1}</param>
       <param name="secondParam">{2}</param>
       <result name="action1" type="chain">Action1</result>
       <result name="action2" type="chain">Action2</result>
</action>
```

And have both actions defined as well like this:

```
<action name="Action1" class="web.Action1" method="execute">
       <result name="success">/WEB-INF/content/Action1.jsp</result>     
       <result name="input">/WEB-INF/content/Action1.jsp</result>
       <result name="error">/WEB-INF/content/Action1.jsp</result>
</action>
```

However, if I invoke URL/parameter/parameter, and then on ProcessRequestAction I return "Action1", I'll get the Action1.jsp (as intended) but all messy, seems like all the CSS is missing. 
First of all, is my approach correct? If so, what I'm I doing wrong here, what can I improve?

Thansk in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why your CSS isn't working, we have no way of knowing--a JSP is a JSP, and follows normal JSP/HTML rules.

As for the first issue: I'd recommend *against* action chaining; it's actively discouraged, and usually just makes a mess of things.

Without knowing more about your application architecture, it's difficult to give targeted advice, but you may find [parameters in namespaces](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-Parametersinnamespaces) helpful.

Even if it's not immediately applicable, you may be able to play games with a `PatternMatcher` or `ActionMapper` that's more targeted to your actual needs--the implementation would depend on a variety of factors, particularly the format(s) of the name, id, and title URL components.

Comment: Using this approach, can I distinguish the action to process by simply using different parameter names such as: @Namespace{"/{ID}/{name}") on Action1 and @Namespace{"/{title}/{ID}") on Action2?

Comment: @Rui I doubt it, since there's no way to distinguish between the two formats without knowing their regex (or other means)--that's why I pointed out the `PatternMatcher` and `ActionMapper` customization options.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few resources that may help you achieve the clean URLs you're looking for:

- [Better URLs with Struts2](http://www.struts2.info/displaycontent/content/better-urls-with-struts2)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772737/hidden-features-of-struts-2-framework/4837917#4837917